# Format address search with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, search, street-address

I have an application that searches a database of addresses. The page visitor enters his or hers address and the app will tell them whether they're connected.

The relevant parts of the database that contains the information they should search against are:

```
streetname      "Stora gatan"
streetnumber    "34"
streetletter    "B"
address         "Stora gatan 34B"
```

This database is provided by my customer and is, as you can see, neatly formatted. The vast vast majority of in-data that the visitor searches for are:

```
"Stora gatan"
"Stora gatan 34"
"Stora gatan 34b"
"Stora gatan 34 b"
```

These are the *only* formats I am currently interested in. This is a swedish application and this is how addresses are formatted/typed in Sweden. Any wild versions of the above (say, if a user should search for "34 Storgatan B" would match nothing and that would be quite ok.

It is also highly undesirable that the application form should have three search fields instead of one, so the in-data is in one string.

Now, as you can see, one of the above search terms will fail in spite of being a legal way to type the address. It's the one with a space between the number and letter of the address.

So I wrote this regexp to catch all incoming searches and hopefully massage them to be correct:

```
if (preg_match("/^(.*?)\s*(\d*?)\s*([A-Za-z]*?)$/", $address, $m)){
    $streetname = uc_words($m[1]);
    $streetnumber = trim($m[2]);
    $streetletter = strtoupper($m[3]);
    $search = trim($streetname . SPACE . $streetnumber . $streetletter);
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't really work as I have hoped. The resulting $m will look like this for each of my examples above:

Wrong:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Stora gatan
    [1] => Stora
    [2] => 
    [3] => gatan
)
```

Correct:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Stora gatan 34
    [1] => Stora gatan
    [2] => 34
    [3] => 
)
```

Correct:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Stora gatan 34b
    [1] => Stora gatan
    [2] => 34
    [3] => b
)
```

Do you guys have any pointers on a catch-all expression or would you suggest doing some more if/else catching prior to the regexp? Any input is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This is more or less impossible. People write adresses in so many different ways (by the way, Norway here). I'd rather go for multiple fields the user fills in. Streetadress, number and so on. What if the user types a comma after the address? Would not that crash your regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (not the most beautiful regular expression, but it works):

```
$address = "Stora gatan 34 b";
preg_match("/([a-zA-Z ]+) ?([0-9]+)? ?([a-zA-Z]+)?/", $address, $m);

print_r($m);
```

Results:

```
$address = "Stora gatan 34 b";
Array ( [0] => Stora gatan 34 b [1] => Stora gatan [2] => 34 [3] => b ) 

$address = "Stora gatan 34b";
Array ( [0] => Stora gatan 34b [1] => Stora gatan [2] => 34 [3] => b ) 

$address = "Stora gatan 34";
Array ( [0] => Stora gatan 34 [1] => Stora gatan [2] => 34 ) 

$address = "Stora gatan";
Array ( [0] => Stora gatan [1] => Stora gatan ) 

$address = "Stora 34 b";
Array ( [0] => Stora 34 b [1] => Stora [2] => 34 [3] => b )
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with that regular expression...  Can you really make it much smaller?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

- create a column that contains the address without spaces: `'Storagatan34B'`
- remove all spaces from the user input string before you search
- use `searchcolumn LIKE <input> + '%'`

Of course, besides spaces you could also remove other characters you wish to ignore. Just make sure you're using the same replacement scheme for the search column and the input.

Comment: Also a good suggestions, but it's a large database and I would prefer to keep it that way unless I had no other option.